# Pass method as parameter Groovy

Tags: groovy, functional-programming

I am creating a Groovy project and I would like to pass a method as a parameter is this possible?

I have 2 methods, which basically do the same thing but have a few small differences, each have different properties.

I would like to send through whether to use the 'buildPayLoad' function or 
'buildSecondPayLoad' into my sendEmail function.

```
    private Operation sendEmail(Order order) {
                  def payload = buildPayload(order, templateId)
    }


    private firstEmailPayLoad buildPayload(Order order, String templateId) {
            new firstEmailPayLoad(
                templateId,
                config.fromAddress,
                order.firstPayLoadProperty,
                buildEmailDataFirstPayLoad(order)
            ).validate()
   }

   private secondEmailPayLoad buildSecondPayLoad(Order order, String templateId) {
            new secondEmailPayLoad(
                templateId,
                config.fromAddress,
                config.bccAddress,
                config.otherProperty,
                order.secondPayLoadProperty
                buildEmailData(order)
            ).validate()
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just do:

```
private Operation sendEmail(Order order, Closure builder) {
    def payload = builder(order, templateId)
}
```

Then call it with:

```
sendEmail(order, this.&buildPayload)
```

Or

```
sendEmail(order, this.&buildSecondPayLoad)
```

BTW:  You really should start class names with a capital letter, so instead of `secondEmailPayLoad`, you should call it `SecondEmailPayLoad` (and the same with `firstEmailPayLoad`)